# AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification not giving callback for the first time

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, avaudioplayer, avsystemcontroller

I want to check if both the volume buttons are working fine. So I set the observer `AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification` to check that.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(volumeCallback(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name("AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"), object: nil)
```

Given is `volumeCallback` method:

```
@objc private func volumeCallback(notification: NSNotification) {
    // check if app is in forground
    guard UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active else {
        return
    }

    //get volume level
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let volumeChangeType = userInfo["AVSystemController_AudioVolumeChangeReasonNotificationParameter"] as? String {
            if volumeChangeType == "ExplicitVolumeChange" {
                print("value changed")

                let level = userInfo["AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"] as? Float
                guard let volLevel = level else {
                    return
                }
                // my work here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, I am not getting callback in `volumeCallback` for the first installation of the app. The weird thing is, this method is being called when the app is in background, but not being called in foreground.

I am using iPhone 5s (iOS 10.3.3).

I don't understand what is the problem in this code. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily done with key-value observer as `AVAudioSession` provides `outputVolume` property. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616533-outputvolume).

You can just add observer on this property and get callbacks.

Here's a simple way of doing this in Swift 5:

```
// Audio session object
private let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
// Observer
private var progressObserver: NSKeyValueObservation!

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    do {
        try session.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("cannot activate session")
    }

    progressObserver = session.observe(\.outputVolume) { [weak self] (session, value) in
        print(session.outputVolume)
    }

    return true
}
```